# Making an API call in React

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I am trying to make an API call in React to return JSON data but I am a bit confused on how to go about this. My API code, in a file API.js, looks like this:

```
import mockRequests from './requests.json'

export const getRequestsSync = () => mockRequests

export const getRequests = () =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => resolve(mockRequests), 500)
})
```

It is retrieving JSON data formatted like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Request from Nancy",
"updated_at": "2015-08-15 12:27:01 -0600",
"created_at": "2015-08-12 08:27:01 -0600",
"status": "Denied"
 }
```

Currently my code to make the API call looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const API = './Api.js'

const Requests = () => ''

export default Requests
```

I've looked at several examples and am still a bit confused by how to go about this. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: In most examples I've seen, fetch looks like the best way to go about it, though I'm struggling with the syntax

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example using a live API (https://randomuser.me/)... It returns an array of objects like in your example:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { people: [], isLoading: true, error: null };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/');
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ people: data.results, isLoading: false });

    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error: error.message, isLoading: false });
    }
  }

  renderPerson = () => {
    const { people, isLoading, error } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <div>{error}</div>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return people.map(person => (
      <div key={person.id.value}>
        <img src={person.picture.medium} alt="avatar" />
        <p>First Name: {person.name.first}</p>
        <p> Last Name: {person.name.last}</p>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderPerson()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Does it make sense? Should be pretty straight forward...

**Live Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gwap6b/**

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me get a grasp on the whole thing

Comment: The one thing I'm still struggling with is fetching from a local file, in this case Api.js as shown in my original post, if I change the fetch to '.Api.js' or './requests.json' I get an error saying unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 which means its getting HTML code instead of JSON

Comment: That's not the issue and I can't really tell from the code you have up... Maybe make a github repo with the full code and post the link here...

Comment: but what if i am not writing api call in Didmount. how to work with loader if i have a special action pages. also i dont want to use dispatch to send a flag to stop the loader.
what i am looking for is to stop loader as soon as i get response from api

Answer (score 3):

You will want to do something like this:

```
var url = 'https://myAPI.example.com/myData';
fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())
          .then(function(data) { /* do stuff with your JSON data */})
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Mozilla has extremely good documentation on using fetch [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Making_fetch_requests) that I highly recommend you read.

The `data` parameter in the second `.then` will be an object parsed from the JSON response you got and you can access properties on it by just using the property label as was in the JSON. For example `data.title` would be `"Request from Nancy"`.

Comment: Could you give an example of what would be in the do stuff with your JSON data area?

Comment: SakoBu's answer is a good example. In their code the second `.then` callback is mapping the JSON object to the component's state (the variable is called `response` instead of `data` but it is the same). Basically you would typically either assign the data to another variable with greater scope or call a function to save the data somewhere.

Comment: but what if i am not writing api call in Didmount. how to work with loader if i have a special action pages. also i dont want to use dispatch to send a flag to stop the loader.
what i am looking for is to stop loader as soon as i get response from api

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling with `fetch`, [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) has a **much simpler** API to work with.

Try this in your API.js file (of course install axios first with `npm i --save axios`):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import mockRequests from './requests.json'

export const getRequests = (url) => {
  if (url) {
    return axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // you need to return the promise
    setTimeout(() => resolve(mockRequests), 500)
  })
})
```

In your component, you can access the `getRequests` function like so

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { getRequests } from './API.js'

class App extends Component {
  state = { 
    data: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    getRequests('http://somedomain.com/coolstuff.json').then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({ data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) return null

    return (
      <div className='App'>
        {this.state.data.title}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: but what if i am not writing api call in Didmount. how to work with loader if i have a special action pages. also i dont want to use dispatch to send a flag to stop the loader.
what i am looking for is to stop loader as soon as i get response from api