# How to show API data in react component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

This is my json URL:

http://ec2-13-233-199-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/keyword/modi

```
{
    "Republic": [
        {
            "headline": "Now, Robert Vadra scoffs at PM Modi's Kedarnath visit, exclaims 'Wow !! What’s going on ...'",
            "link": "https://www.republicworld.com/india-news/general-news/now-robert-vadra-scoffs-at-pm-modis-kedarnath-visit-exclaims-wow-whats-going-on-dot",
            "date": "2019-05-19 20:51:07.261913",
            "category": null,
            "sentiment": null
        }
    ],
    "Ndtv": [
        {
            "headline": "Blog: Is Modi Moving Mamata Banerjee's Cheese In Bengal?",
            "link": "https://www.ndtv.com/blog/is-modi-moving-mamata-banerjees-cheese-in-bengal-2039156?pfrom=home-opinion",
            "date": "2019-05-19 20:51:50.218228",
            "category": null,
            "sentiment": null
        }
    ],
    "Indiatv": [
        {
            "headline": "Modi's Kedarnath Yatra is being widely covered by media, this is gross violation of MCC: TMC to Election Commission",
            "link": "https://www.indiatvnews.com/news/india-election-2019-modi-kedarnath-yatra-is-being-widely-covered-by-media-this-is-gross-violation-of-mcc-tmc-to-election-commission-520982",
            "date": "2019-05-19 20:50:48.145723",
            "category": null,
            "sentiment": null
        }
    ],
    "Thehindu": [
        {
            "headline": "Early life stress can modify DNA expression, a study finds",
            "link": "https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/early-life-stress-can-modify-dna-expression-a-study-finds/article27172334.ece",
            "date": "2019-05-19 20:50:51.485027",
            "category": null,
            "sentiment": null
        }
    ],
    "Zeenews": [
        {
            "headline": "Lok Sabha election 2019: PM Modi offers prayers at Badrinath temple\n",
            "link": "https://zeenews.india.com/video/india/lok-sabha-election-2019-pm-modi-offers-prayers-at-badrinath-temple-2204365.html",
            "date": "2019-05-19 20:50:55.60367",
            "category": null,
            "sentiment": null
        }
    ],
}
```

I have written the following code to show headline link date of news Source Republic, Ndtv, Zeenews in my react component:

```
class keywordNews extends Component {
    state = {
        data:[]
      }
      componentDidMount(){
          const keyword=localStorage.getItem('keyword');
          const url=`http://ec2-13-233-199-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/keyword/${keyword}`;
          console.log(url);
          axios.get(url)
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({data:res.data.Republic
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        });

      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{localStorage.getItem('keyword')}</h1>
        <Show data={this.state.data} /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Show Component:

```
 class Show extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.data.map(({headline,link,date }, index) => 
                    <div key={index}>
                        <div>
                            <h3><a href={link}>{headline}</a></h3> 
                            <h6>{date}</h6>           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 )}   
        </div>  
           <br></br>
            </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Show;
```

From the above code, I am getting headline link of only Republic array. But I want to write code for all the index in the array such as Ndtv, Indiatv, The Hindu.

I am new to front end development. Please help me how can I show all my data from the API.

Comment: In componentDidMount You are taking data only for Republic this.setState({data:res.data.Republic});

Comment: Yes, What should I do for all others?

Comment: @imsaiful Instead of assigning republic, get the whole data to the component state and then iterate the data. So it will be like this.state.data.republic.map()

Comment: Ok, I will do that but what should I do other like Zeenews,ndtv etc. It will be better if you write the answer to this only for the component. Thanks.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892435/making-an-api-call-in-react/48892724#48892724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through the object to render the data, here is how you do it.

Save the whole data object to the state (not just Republic)

```
class KeywordNews extends Component {
    state = {
        data:{}
      }
      componentDidMount(){
          const keyword=localStorage.getItem('keyword');
          const url=`http://ec2-13-233-199-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/keyword/${keyword}`;
          console.log(url);
          axios.get(url)
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({data:res.data
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        });

      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{localStorage.getItem('keyword')}</h1>
        <Show data={this.state.data} /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now loop that Object in the `Show` component,

```
class Show extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  RenderData = () => {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      return (
        <div key={key}>
        { data[key].map(({headline, date, link}, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <h1> Chanel: {key} </h1>
              <h3> Headline: {headline} </h3>
              <h4> Date: {date} </h4>
            </div>
          )
        })}


          <br/>
          <br />
        </div>
      )
    }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { RenderData } = this;
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {data && <RenderData />}
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but I am getting data is not defined in Object.keys(data).map((key)

Comment: I have edited the code. I have messed up with `const { data } = this.props;` which should be in the `RenderData` function. And also for consistency, change your `data: []` to `data: {}`, which I have also changed above.

Comment: now getting error data not defined at this line {data && <RenderData />}

Comment: I defined it with const { RenderData } = this;
      const { data } = this; but not getting any headline or other info. here is the source file link https://github.com/imsaiful/save4thpillar/blob/master/save4thpillar/src/Container/News/Show.js

Comment: Now it should work. `data` is coming as a `props`, so `const { data } = this;` should be `const { data } = this.props;`.

Comment: sir new error TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined on RenderData()

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if that works. If we use `RenderData = () => {}`, class level `this` keyword is available in the function scope.

Comment: I am very thankful for you. Please suggest me some article medium blog to learn this I mean how to iterate over API request. Actually, I was only doing ds algorithm and Django in past. Just move to react. But I don't find any article related to my this problem. Thanks

Comment: Learn the javascript basic (especially Object and Arrays). You first need to understand what the data type is ( in this case object) and then how you can loop through that data type.